# Unable to get UIView/Frame of navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

My application in Swift 5 have a navigationItem displayed at top right corner using

```
override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var deleteNavBarItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem:.trash, target: self, action: #selector(deleteButtonOnClick))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = deleteNavBarItem

    ...
}
```

Due to some requirements, we want to display some custom subview base on the position of navigation bar item position.

Hence I want to get the relative position/`frame` for this `rightBarButtonItem` of whole view.

I have tried to using code below by some of the answers providing from forum.

```
let view1 = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.value(forKeyPath: "view") as? UIView
let view2 = deleteNavBarItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
```

However both of the `view1` & `view2` return nil.

Is there any alternative solution to find the `frame`/`UIView` of `rightBarButtonItem`?

Kindly advise.

Comment: where you called this code

Answer (score 0):

create a bar button outlet and use the following code to get the frame

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var rightBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let barButtonFrame = rightBarButton.perform(#selector(getter: UIViewController.view)).takeRetainedValue().frame {
            print(barButtonFrame) // prints (0.0, 0.0, 42.0, 44.0)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom bar button with `UIView/UIButton`and add button in rightBarButtonItem.

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "getstarted"), for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(callMethod), for: .touchUpInside)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [barButton]
```